# Issue Setting Up MariaDB as a CentOS7 Service

Tags: c++, service, centos7, mariadb-10.3

I have built MariaDB from source for CentOS 7

```
yum-builddep mariadb-server
yum install git \
  gcc \
  gcc-c++ \
  bison \
  libxml2-devel \
  libevent-devel \
  rpm-build
  git clone --branch 10.3 https://github.com/MariaDB/server.git
  cmake -DRPM=centos7 server/
  make package
```

This has created the following `rpm` files.

```
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-backup.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-client.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-common.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-connect-engine.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-devel.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-gssapi-server.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-rocksdb-engine.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-server.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-shared.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-test.rpm
MariaDB-10.3.29-centos7-x86_64-tokudb-engine.rpm
```

I'd appreciate any help on what should be done next to be able to

- run MariaDB as a service, and
- being able to develop c++ code using MariaDB.

I tried the following commands and CentOS complains about finding mariadb service.

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

Comment: `.rpm` are installation packages, you probably need to at least install the server package.  Consult your system docs for installing packages. Consult the `MariaDB` docs for what each package is.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. Is it the `devel` package for C++ development?